# Craft3, Plugin Craft Commerce, Tax without percentages

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, tax

Is it possible to set Tax in the Rate field other than percentage?.

In Tax I want to place an example amount: 10.50 without percentages.

Comment: It sounds like you’re trying to set some sort of service or handling fee?

Comment: Exactly, I need to implement it that way because of the client requirement! :D @RitterKnight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible to charge a fixed tax fee natively, it needs to be a percentage. You can however implement your own tax [adjuster](https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/extend/adjusters.html#writing-an-adjuster) within a plugin or module, which is what Craft is doing under the hood.

You can specify an amount on the adjuster with a type of `tax` and it will then show on orders within Craft.